# How to copy only the rows of text from a column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I routinely need to extract the text from files that look like this:

[image: Screenshot of the file in Excel]

Ideally, in two ways:

1. Just the individual rows of text

   Ex:
   done we actually have a publication out

   of this data and we are working on on

   more data that was recently presented at
2. In paragraph form (joining the text from different rows into a single block of text that I can edit in Word, Google Docs, etc)

   Ex:
   done we actually have a publication out of this data and we are working on on more data that was recently presented at

When I receive the files, everything is in Column A.  There are two rows of numbers I don’t need, followed by a row of text I do need, and then a blank row, after which the pattern repeats for thousands of rows.

Obviously, doing this manually takes a long time, so any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to extract the data of every third row of A column i.e. A3, A7, A10 ....

Firstly, please write 3, 7 in first two cells of B Column and drag down to produce a series like 3, 7, 10, 13 .....

Now, write the formula =INDIRECT("A"&B1) in C1 which will show the text of A3 cell. Copy the formula down to show the text of A7, A10 and so on.

[image]

To combine all the text, you can use CONCAT or TEXTJOIN functions if you have Excel 2016. The benefit of TEXTJOIN is that you can use delimiter like space or comma between the texts. You can also ignore empty cells. In the following example, space has been used as delimiter and True has been used to ignore empty cells.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,C1:C11)
```

For earlier versions, you can use CONCATENATE function but you have to write all cell references one by one.

```
=CONCATENATE(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8).
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. The only issue was that the text exceeds the limit of the TEXTJOIN function, but that was easy to get around by splitting it into various cells. (From Microsoft: If the resulting string exceeds 32767 characters (cell limit), TEXTJOIN returns the #VALUE! error. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Comment: I was not aware of this limitation of TEXTJOIN. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this that doesn't involve writing some code. You can probably do it with VBA in Excel, but I don't have much experience with that.

Here's an example of how you could do it in Python. This script will go through the cells in a given column and print the value to a file if it doesn't start with a number.

Excel sheet:

[Sample excel sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGwuk.png)

Output:

```
Here's the first string and the second now a third
```

Code:

```python
from openpyxl import load_workbook # package for working with xls files
import re # regex package

workbookName = 'test.xlsx'
sheetName = 'Sheet1'
column = 'A'
maxRow = 50
outputFile = 'excelOutput.txt'

# Open the workbook
wb = load_workbook(workbookName)
# Create a file to put the data into
fh = open(outputFile, 'w')

# Loop through all the rows
for kk in range(1,maxRow):
    # Grab the cell's value
    cellValue = wb[sheetName][column+str(kk)].value
    # If the cell isn't empty
    if cellValue != None:
        # If the cell doesn't start with a number
        if not re.search("\\d",str(cellValue)[0]):
            # Write the value from the cell into the text file
            fh.write(cellValue)
# Close the file
fh.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify deleting of unwanted rows in the range, it is best to sort them first, so that f.ex. all empty rows are grouped together. It is rather simple to use built-in sorting of cells, but to maintain the initial order of the texts, a few extra steps are required.

I will refer to your data as being in range `A1:A200` as an example. Adjust as needed to your actual data.

1. Insert the digit `1` in cell `B1` and the digit `2` in cell `B2`. Select the cells `B1:B200` and apply the `fill`, `linear` function to end up with 1 to 200 in column `B`. Later this will help returning the texts in their initial order.
2. Select the range `A1:B200` and apply sorting. You will now have the numeric rows grouped together as well as the time frame rows, text rows and the empty rows. Thus it is easy to select and remove the rows you don't want to keep. After deleting unwanted rows, you should have a range, say `A1:B50` with the texts and their original row numbers in column `B`.
3. To reinstate the correct order of the texts select the range `A1:B50` and sort it on column `B`.

To copy the texts to `Word` for further processing, select, copy and paste into `Word`. Remove the table formatting and concatenate the rows with search and replace (search `paragraph` and replace with `space`).